# How to add equations' left and right sides together?

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation

If we have two equations E1 and E2, and instead of using `Solve` to solve it, we simply need to manually add them up which would allow some simplification that could lead to better visibility of its structure, I found that

```
E1 + E2
```

would always fail. Instead, I need to extract left and right sides of an equation explicity using

```
E1[[1]] + E2[[1]] == E1[[2]] + E2[[2]]
```

[image]

Is there any built-in function to do this?

Comment: Hey Jim, in general we don't put names under posts on this site, because we have the box on the left with your user information. Why don't you change your user name to something better than `user2452474` to make you more recognizable? Go [to your user profile](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7883/user2452474) and click on *edit*.

Comment: Another thing, when you write a question and post code, please review [the most common pitfalls in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/187). Specifically, don't use capitalized variable names. When you include code, please use code blocks so that everyone can copy and paste your example.

Comment: @halirutan Just learned how to paste code. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need is `Thread`, to thread the plus operator over the equations:

```
e1 = 3 a == b;
e2 = 6 c == d;
Thread[e1 + e2, Equal]
(* 3 a + 6 c == b + d *)
```

Comment: I tested and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
Inner[Plus, e1, e2, Equal]
```

> 3 a + 6 c == b + d