# Manipulating Equations: Substracting two equations

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I was wondering why I fail to substract two equations using thread, while it works properly, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26792/how-to-add-equations-left-and-right-sides-together) for additions.

Example: Let a system of equations be given:

```
eq1 = a + b == c
eq2 = a - b == c
```

I can add both equations (1) + (2) using using Thread:

```
Thread[eq1 + eq2, Equal]
```

which gives the correct result:

```
a == c
```

However, when I substract the two eqations (1)-(2) via

```
Thread[eq1 - eq2, Equal]
```

I get

```
a + b - (a - b == c) == c - (a - b == c)
```

and simplifying it gives me the first equation.

```
a + b == c
```

Can anyone tell me why Thread does not work with a minus sign? 
Sorry if this is a trivial question.

Comment: You could use `SubtractSides[eq1, eq2]`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem more efficiently. It also works if I multiply the equation by -1 via Thread[eq1*-1,Equal] and add it via Thread, but I was wondering *why* Thread fails.

Comment: By entering `Subtract[eq1, eq2] // FullForm` you see that it actually evaluates to `Plus[eq1,Times[-1,eq2]]`, and the effect is that the equation will be multiplied by `-1` and the threading operates again on the outer `Plus` part, which gives the result you see.